# how to tcnative-1.dll configuration in intellij idea

Tags: java, tomcat, intellij-idea

When I run Tomcat Server 7.0 (Window XP) it display error:

> The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal
>   performance in production environments was not found on the
>   java.library.path:

how to add tcnative-1.dll in Intellij Idea?

Comment: Why do you want to? It's a transparent performance improvement, and tomcat works fine without it, and you're just debugging.

Comment: i just want add for tomcat running performance.